# How to test (minitest) get with locale in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, minitest

I'm trying to figure out how to test (minitest) a route that has locale and is within a scope:

```
  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    get 'static_pages/about'
    resources :salas    
  end
```

This doesn't work:

```
require 'test_helper'

class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "should get about" do
    get :about
    assert_response :success
  end

end
```

and will produce the following output:

```
# Running:

E

Finished in 0.301302s, 3.3189 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"about", :controller=>"static_pages"}
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:5:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

rake routes:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                       

    Controller#Action
static_pages_about GET    /:locale/static_pages/about(.:format) static_pages#about {:locale=>/en|es/}
             salas GET    /:locale/salas(.:format)              salas#index {:locale=>/en|es/}
                   POST   /:locale/salas(.:format)              salas#create {:locale=>/en|es/}
          new_sala GET    /:locale/salas/new(.:format)          salas#new {:locale=>/en|es/}
         edit_sala GET    /:locale/salas/:id/edit(.:format)     salas#edit {:locale=>/en|es/}
              sala GET    /:locale/salas/:id(.:format)          salas#show {:locale=>/en|es/}
                   PATCH  /:locale/salas/:id(.:format)          salas#update {:locale=>/en|es/}
                   PUT    /:locale/salas/:id(.:format)          salas#update {:locale=>/en|es/}
                   DELETE /:locale/salas/:id(.:format)          salas#destroy {:locale=>/en|es/}
                   GET    /*path(.:format)                      redirect(301, /en/%{path})
              root GET    /                                     salas#index
```

I think that maybe I need to pass the locale to the test but I'not sure how. 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little below this heading: [Function Tests for your Controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers) in the Rails Guide: A Guide to Testing Rails shows the get method's convention.  To pass params to the method, include it as the second parameter to the call.

```
get :about, locale: 'en'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked ! I will check the guide. Thanks !